# How to execute some code before flask socket.io server starts?

Tags: python, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

I have an application based on flask-socketIO. I want to execute some code just before flask server starts.
My app.py file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
CORS(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print("Client connected")


@socketio.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I run the program: `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0`, I get console output as follows:  `* Serving Flask-SocketIO app "app"`
Then some clients connect to my app and it works as I expected, but I want to see `print` which is above `socketio.run(app)`.

How can I execute code before the start of the server?

Comment: Does it not already run ? Because python is an interpreted language so it should print.

Comment: It doesn't run, but I can execute code before server starts if I put it(code) below imports, but I think that it isn't pythonic solution.

Comment: No. Added after python isnt the right way.See if you can create a custom function and call that before ` socket.run() `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `before_fist_request`

```
@app.before_first_request
def your_function():
    print("execute before server starts")
```

Update:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me, at the beginning of my app.py file I have: 
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
I also tried to @socketio.before_first_request, but I get an error that socketio has no attribute 'before_first_request'

Comment: @trojek It's should work otherwise you have setup this in wrong way... Can you include all of your `app.py` code. So I can take the look...

Comment: Probably I have some problems with environment.